# Regex that starts with IN and ends with eight digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like build a regular expression for "IN12345678" (i.e., starts with IN and ends with eight digit, totally 10).

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will do what you require `^IN\d{8}$`

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for your case

```
/^IN[0-9]{8}$/
```